# ASP.Net Database query exception for one table even though another works

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database-connection, dbcontext

I need suggestions on what the problem could be to the break in my program. I am getting the following error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

for a query from one controller but not another that runs off the same DbContext connection.

I decided to restart from scratch with a generic ASP.Net Core WebAPI template. I inserted my two classes below, ran a build, and scaffolded them into Controllers and Views with no issue. I even have the ability from the SQL Server Object Explorer (in Visual Studio 2015 Community) to "View Data" that is in both tables. I even took out the Foreign Key reference in the Order class to the Company class. This is all within a test environment on one machine with me with admin rights and dbo on DB.

```
public class Order{ }
public class Company { } 

public class DataMineDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DataMineDbContext(DbContextOptions<DataMineDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public virtual DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
}

public class CompaniesController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataMineDbContext _context;

    public CompaniesController(DataMineDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }

    // GET: Companies
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Company.ToListAsync()); //this works
    }
}

public class OrdersController : Controller
{
    private readonly DataMineDbContext _context;

    public OrdersController(DataMineDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }

    // GET: Orders
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Order.ToListAsync()); //this throws error
        //An unhandled exception of NullReferenceException
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I can type in the URL for my create view for the Order controller and it  will insert a new record into the DB, yet error on the redirect to "Index"

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int id, [Bind("Color,CompanyId,Delivered,Filled,ItemName,OrderNumb,Ordered,Price,Qty,Size")] Order order)
    {
        order.CompanyId = id;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(order);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(order);
    }
}
```

SIDE NOTE: I have my individual account login setup on a separate DB within the same server. I can also Register a user (insert) into the AspNetUsers table, but when I log off and try to log in it always fails. Not sure when this started occurring maybe these issues are part of the same problem; yet unsure why only one table allows for a lookup, but they all allow for an update. Also beyond my experience whether this is a Visual Studio issue or a SQL Server issue.

Update: After Max's comment I changed my connectionString to

> "Data Source={ServerName}\{InstanceName}; Initial Catalog={DatabaseName}; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=15; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

for both my userLogin database and my appDatabase. This allowed my to log back in for the user. It did not however let me query the Order table. I therefore tried a new class, State (which as Name/Code of all US states), I then scaffolded out the controller and views. The query works now for both Company and State but not Order. So I thought it had to do with the virtual keyword in the DataMineDbContext for the DBSets, as State did not scaffold that in. But that did not fix my issue. I therefore though it was a naming convention thing and renamed Order to Purchase both in the app and in my Database. This has not helped.

Comment: and are you sure Order has value in database?

Comment: @Usman Yes two records. " I even have the ability from the SQL Server Object Explorer to "View Data" that is in both tables." Also this is only an issue in Index and Edit with a lookup. If I type in a Create URL it takes me to the view and will save a new record. I even updated the code to show the Create Action in the Order Controller

Comment: Check if is present `MultipleActiveResultSets=true;` on your connection string

Comment: @Max Its not, though I think at one point I did. As stated maybe I broke something when I was trying to clean up in this case non-essential stuff in the connection string.. If you would like to add an answer, about using [MARS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx) with link explaining how the do exactly that it throws an error from lazy loading. And maybe a solution or reason why the default template lazy loads?  Actually I put it in both connection strings and it didn't help.String = "Data Source=**;Initial Catalog=**;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;"

Comment: @Max I added an update. Anymore suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the startup code where you register the context?

Comment: @Max Thanks for your efforts. If you would like to read the solution that fixed my problem, please read the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have learned from Mr. Brownstone on [Database Adminstrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168055/query-not-working-is-it-issue-with-vs-2015-community-asp-net-core-webapi-or-sql?noredirect=1#comment325302_168055) That it came down to my Order model class having properties not properly set for nullable types to match my database table setup. In this instance for DATETIME? nullable.

I will repost the links [NRE crash when property isn't marked as nullable.](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6818) and [Null reference when using Take](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5112)